# Restricting Access to Dynamodb Items from AWS GUI

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a dynamodb table that is being accessed by an IAM user via the application; but the problem is any admin user logged-in to AWS Console can navigate to the dynamodb table and view the items in it. As per our security policy; this shouldn't be allowed.

Can anyone suggest if it's possible to block access to the dynamodb Items from the AWS GUI?

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB does not support resource based policies. So there are two work arounds.

1. Create an IAM policy that denies access to the DynamoDB table and apply this policy to all IAM users. You would also have to deny access disallowing certain IAM actions to prevent the admin users from removing the deny DynamoDB access policy. IAM permissions boundaries might be able to help you with this. Update your application to use an IAM role instead of an IAM user.
2. Use client side encryption on the DynamoDB data so the admins can only view the encrypted data in DynamoDB. You could use KMS for this but depending on how you manage the encryption, KMS costs could far exceed the DynamoDB costs.